# Getting All Records where Particular Column is empty in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a query in Access where I have to get all the records where a particular column is empty, how I can do this?

This is what I am thinking it should be, but its not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE PARTICULARCOLUMN = ''
```

Comment: Have you tried Is Null? It is the best solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only return rows that have an empty field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651717/only-return-rows-that-have-an-empty-field)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would handle both empty strings ('') and NULL values in the column.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Nz(PARTICULARFIELD,'') = ''
```

Comment: Doesn't this set the value of the where clause to be " WHERE '' = '' " whenever the PARTICULARFIELD is null?

Comment: I see... slight misinterpretation of the question... Thanks

Comment: It is most unlikely, but not impossible, that you have zero-length strings, Null is far more likely. The statement above is not sargable and will be slow to run on large tables.

Answer (score 6):

Try...

```
WHERE PARTICULARFIELD Is Null
```

Sample from Web:

```
SELECT [Table1].[CustomerID], [Table2].[CustomerID]
FROM [Table1] LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON [Table1].[CustomerID] = [Table2].[CustomerID]
WHERE ((([Table 2].[CustomerID]) Is Null));
```

See:  http://www.fabalou.com/access/Queries/isnullquery.asp

Comment: You do not need all those parentheses in the WHERE statement, but +1 for Is Null.

Comment: @Renous: last time this came up (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651717/only-return-rows-that-have-an-empty-field) you asserted that zero-length strings and space-filled strings should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to find all records with a particular field empty. Not NULL didn't work. This did: WHERE ((Not (table.field)="").

So, to find both the empties and the nulls, just to be sure...

```
WHERE (((table.field)="" Or (table.field) Is Null)
```