# Combining Select Into and Alter table

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to combine Select Into and Alter Table (ms access sql):

```
SELECT table1.field1
INTO table2
FROM table1;
```

And second one:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN ID autoincrement;
```

I was trying UNION ALL but I got message 'action query can't be used as row source'. 
Is it possible to combine them using different syntax?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Can I use different syntax to generate new table based on existing one and add one column with auto-increment ID fields in one statement?

Comment: You could create a macro and add the different SQLs as RunSQL actions.

Comment: You are better off first creating the table, then inserting the data.

Comment: Yes, but I tried to find the way to run them as one. Anyway thank you for answers.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894673/counter-field-in-ms-access-how-to-generate) is a function for counting records in a query, you can add it as a field to the `Insert... Into` query. Real auto increment is created on an empty table

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix [Data Manipulation Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) (DML) with [Data Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) (DDL).

You'll need to execute both statements separately, or to create a stored procedure which contains both commands.