# how to query access database and retrieve values based on some criteria's from excel vba

Tags: ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007, vba

Can you please help with access database queries from excel vba

My algorithm is as follows:

---

Open connection to access database

Select  table1.column1, table1.column2, table1.column3 where table1.column3.value = “x” and table1.column2.value = “y”

Switch Case 1: If **no records found matching the criteria** from access database

Insert some values etc…

Switch Case 2 : If **records found matching the criteria** from access database

No action needed

Switch Case 3 : If **records found not matching the criteria** values from access database

Should display the values in an datagridview in excel vba

Should not allow to insert values

---

Kindly help me with the code needed from excel vba

Thanks
Prabu M

Comment: Search SO for `[ms-access] [excel] ado`

Comment: See this link. It will give you the basic idea on how to proceed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083232/writing-excel-vba-to-receive-data-from-access/9085127#9085127

Comment: thanks dude but can you help me how to use switch case based on no records found from access DB or records not matching the criteria

Comment: @Prabu Mike: Strange, I missed this question. Would request you to use "@" and my name as I have done for you when replying so that I get an intimation that you replied :) Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

note that the `case3` an `case1` are similar

you can use this code

```vb
    Dim recSet As Recordset
    Set recSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select table1.column1, table1.column2,"_ 
           & "table1.column3 where table1.column3.value = 'x' and table1.column2.value = 'y'")
    If recSet.EOF Then 'No records matching criteria
        'Do something
    Else 'There was records found
        'Do Something else
    End If
```