# Looping through an array and posting array to table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am an old Foxpro programmer and I use to use arrays to post variable fields.

What I am trying to do is I have 15 date fields in the new table I designed.
In my query I have individual records with one date for activity.

I want to compile the 15 different dates for a each `Client_id` into one record with 15 dates but I can't seem to reference the table data as an array.
I have tried a couple different methods of defining the array but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code that I have. In my table I have 15 date fields named `Mail_date1`, `Mail_date2`, `Mail_date3`, etc.
I tried first defining it just as an array but did not like it; my code always fails when I try to reference the date field in the result table `rs2!mdate2 = memdate(intcounter)`

1. How can I reference my result table output fields as an array?
2. Do I have to put a whole bunch of if statements to load my results?
   Seems like a waste.... should be able to load them as an array.

I am a new Access 2007 VBA programmer.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Dim FinTotal, intcounter As Integer
Dim FinMPU, FinVersion As String
Dim mail_date(1 To 15) As Date
Dim memdate(1 To 15) As Date
Dim mdate2 As String

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset( _
            "SELECT NewFile.MPU_ID,   " & _
            "       NewFile.MAIL_DATE," & _
            "       NewFile.TOTAL,    " & _ 
            "       Freight.Version   " &_
            "FROM Freight " & _
            "  LEFT JOIN NewFile ON Freight.[MPU ID] = NewFile.MPU_ID " & _
            "ORDER BY NewFile.MPU_ID, NewFile.MAIL_DATE")

Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Final")

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE Final.* FROM Final;"

intcounter = 1
memdate(intcounter) = rs1!mail_date
FinMPU = rs1!mpu_ID
FinTotal = rs1!total
FinVersion = rs1!Version
rs1.MoveNext

On Error GoTo Error_MayCauseAnError

Do While Not rs1.EOF
    Do While Not rs1.EOF _
             And memdate(intcounter) <> rs1!mail_date _
             And FinMPU = rs1!mpu_ID
        intcounter = intcounter + 1
        memdate(intcounter) = rs1!mail_date
        FinTotal = FinTotal + rs1!total
        FinVersion = rs1!Version
        FinMPU = rs1!mpu_ID
        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

    If FinMPU <> rs1!mpu_ID Then
        rs2.AddNew
        mdate2 = "mail_date" & CStr(intcounter)
        rs2!mdate2 = memdate(intcounter)
        rs2!total = FinTotal
        rs2!mpu_ID = FinMPU
        rs2!Version = FinVersion
        rs2.Update

        FinTotal = rs1!total
        FinVersion = rs1!Version
        FinMPU = rs1!mpu_ID
        intcounter = 1
        memdate(intcounter) = rs1!mail_date
    End If
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: DAO is a dead end. Do not use it anymore for new code.

Comment: @Tomalak Umm, no. For native Access applications using the ACE database engine, the "Microsoft Office ... Access Database Engine Object Library" (which maps to `DAO` in VBA) is still the default and preferred access method.

Comment: @Gord IIRC they have switched to ADO as the default library as of Access 2007 (?).

Comment: @Tomalak `DAO` is still the default and native way to handle data in Access 2007/2010/2013 as it has been updated to support the enhancement of the new database format.  You are completely free to us `ADO` of course; there are some things you can do in one that cannot be done in the other and vice-versa. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039224/is-it-better-to-use-ado-or-dao-in-access-2007

Comment: @Tomalak Back around Access_2000 (or maybe Access_97) Microsoft replaced DAO with ADO as the default reference for new VBA projects (to push people toward using SQL Server backends). This was not popular with the Access developer community, and in Access_2003 Microsoft put the default DAO reference back in and gave it precedence over ADO. Then, in Access_2007 (IIRC) Microsoft dropped the default ADO reference and (the "new, improved") "DAO" was once again the sole default reference for data access.

Comment: @GordThompson I see. This is the bit I was missing. I was pushed into SQL Server. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

first, if you expect and answer, you should really spend more time on properly formatting your explanation and your code...

Now, for some remarks and possible answer to the question:

- You should `DELETE FROM Final` before you open that table in a recordset.
- You should be explicit about the type of recordset you are opening:

  ```
  ' Open as Read-only '
  Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordSet("...", dbOpenSnapshot)
  ' Open as Read/Write '
  Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordSet("...", dbOpenDynaset)
  ```
- You should  `Dim memdate(1 To 15) As Variant` instead of `Date` as the `Date` datatype cannot be `Null`, and since you are pulling data from a LEFT JOIN, it's possible that the returned values could be `Null` if there are no corresponding data to `Freight` in the table `Newfile`.
- That `On Error GoTo Error_MayCauseAnError` should probably not be there.
  Use `On Error Goto` only to catch errors you can't deal with at all.
  Using that here will only hide errors in your code. With some proper checks statements you should not even need the `On Error Goto`...
- It looks like your first internal loop is trying to skip some records.
  However, when that loop breaks, it could be because it reached EOF, and you never test for that in the code that follows the loop.
- You never test if your `intcounter` goes beyond the 15 allocated dates.
  Are you absolutely sure that you can never have more than 15 records?
- You do not say which error message you get exactly. That could be useful to help determine the kind of issue at hand.

Comment: You should also include that `Dim FinTotal, intcounter As Integer` would declare `FinTotal` a variant. Assuming that it would be `Integer` as well is a common mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
mdate2 = "mail_date" & CStr(intcounter)
rs2!mdate2 = memdate(intcounter)
```

Use

```
rs2.Fields("mail_date" & intcounter).Value = memdate(intcounter)
```

the `!` syntax of DAO really only is a shorthand for the longer `rs.Fields("name")` form.

Comment: Of course the explicit use of `.Value` still is completely optional.