# How to handle arrays in Access tables

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, field

I have a table in MS-Access that needs to contain an array of 4 (type number) values. At the moment they are in named fields, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4. However, that’s cumbersome (the number of values may be larger) because I want to use a loop in the associated VBA code, which generates a binary data file from the database tables.

Is it possible for VBA to access table fields using raw index values? As an example, if I have a table with the following fields:

Name
VAL1
VAL2
VAL3
VAL4

Can I reference fields using generic names and indices, so that my 4 VAL fields can be accessed in a loop using a structure such as TableName.field(i)?

Comment: No, not really.  In cases like this go down not across, i.e. have another table with `name_id | value_id | value` - so 4 rows per name relating to each value.

Comment: You can loop the fields of a recordset, see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11548697/3820271 (use `rs.Fields(n).Value` to get the value). But as Alex wrote, you should probably change your table design. And use Crosstab query / Pivot to get a tabular view.

Comment: Note that index begins with 0. Also, for similarly named fields, can dynamically construct the field name and reference that: `rs.Fields("Val" & n)`. However, since you probably need to reference all fields, not just the similar named ones, use the index reference.

Comment: @BruceV - Are you saying you want (n) number of values to be contained in one column / field, rather than multiple columns, and you want to be able to iterate the values?

Comment: as alex k mentioned you can use secondary table 1:N relationship to have all your sub values. or if your application can handle, use JSON and save the array as string. Any loop operation must extract the json array first before accessing the content!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through an array and posting array to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637850/looping-through-an-array-and-posting-array-to-table)

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be a lot better for you now, and especially in the long run, if you name your fields relevant to what they actually represent.  That's my .02.